# How can I change UART pins in DTS U-boot?

Tags: linux, embedded, u-boot, microprocessors, texas-instruments

We are making custom board based on TI am5728 sitara family.
We've got am5728 Evaluation Module and tried to make our custom board with minimum differences.
In this evm u-boot and linux boot log goes throw UART3 С28 and D27 pins and we need to use UART3 too, but on AB3 and Y1 pins.

We found in u-boot sources files in arch/arm/dts/am57xx-beagle-x15.dts this code:

```
uart3_pins_default: uart3_pins_default {
pinctrl-single,pins = <
  0x3f8 (PIN_INPUT_SLEW | MUX_MODE2) /* uart2_ctsn.uart3_rxd */
  0x3fc (PIN_INPUT_SLEW | MUX_MODE1) /* uart2_rtsn.uart3_rxd */
>; };
```

and changed it to this:

```
uart3_pins_default: uart3_pins_default {
pinctrl-single,pins = <
  0x24c (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE0) /* uart3_txd.uart3_txd */
  0x34c (PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE4) /* mcasp_axr0.uart3_rxd */
  0x3f8 (PIN_INPUT_SLEW | MUX_MODE15) /* uart2_ctsn.uart3_rxd */
  0x3fc (PIN_INPUT_SLEW | MUX_MODE15) /* uart2_rtsn.uart3_txd */
>;  };
```

But if we try this u-boot on our custom board, we can see no loading log.
And if we try this u-boot on evm board, we can see loading log.

So we can think that this changes in code do nothig, but U-boot definitely use this dts file, because if we change UART3 to UART2, we can't see loading log in evm.

So why can't we change UART pins? Is there one more place that we need to change?

Thanks

p.s.
Topic in TI forum:
https://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/linux/f/354/p/585273/2151268

Comment: The original one sets `2 inputs`. Yours `1 output` and `3 inputs`.... What about the device that uses `uart3_pins_default`?

Comment: hmm.. It's very interesting.
The original one code sets 2 inputs, but in datasheet one pin is input and another pin is output.
I tried to set both our pins to PIN_INPUT_PULLUP, but is has nothing changed - U-boot shows log on evm, and doesn't show it on our custom board.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in UART pins.

We have build our U-boot without FIT check and it has successfully started.